# Jensen's inequality integral version for strongly convex functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, optimization, convex-analysis, jensen-inequality

For a convex function $\phi$, not necessarily differentiable. If $\mu$ is a probability measure, and $f$ and $\phi(f)$ are integrable. We have:
$$
\phi \left( \int f \, d\mu \right) \leq \int \phi(f) \, d\mu
$$
If I recall correctly, the intuition of the proof is that $\phi$ has a subgradient at $\int f \, d\mu$, which in other words, the convex function is bounded below by a linear approximation.

> Now for a strongly convex function, let's assume it to be differentiable. Is there any generalization of Jensen's inequality in this case? Strongly convex is defined as there exist $m > 0$ s.t. $f(y) \geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^{\top}(y-x)+\frac{m}{2}\|y-x\|^{2}_{2}$ for all $x,y$.

Since this is a quadratic lower bound, I felt that there should be one. However, I am not aware of any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\phi$ is a strongly convex function with parameter $m$ then function
$$\phi(x) - \frac{m}{2}x^2 \triangleq \psi(x)$$
is also a convex function. For details see [this article.](https://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/strong-convexity) If you apply Jensen's inequality to $\psi$ instead of $\phi$ you obtain
$$
\phi\left ( \int f d\mu\right ) - \frac{m}{2}\left( \int f d\mu\right )^2 = \psi\left ( \int f d\mu \right ) \leq \int\psi(f) d\mu = \int\phi(f) - \frac{m}{2}f^2 d\mu
$$
Re-arranging the first and the last you end up with
\begin{align}
\phi\left ( \int f d\mu\right ) &\leq \int\phi(f)d\mu - \frac{m}{2} \left[\int f^2d\mu - \left(\int fd\mu\right)^2\right ] \\
&= \int\phi(f)d\mu - \frac{m}{2}\text{Var}_{\mu}(f)
\end{align}
The variance term is quadratic like you have suggested. Also since the variance is non-negative, this approach can provide a tighter bound than Jensen's inequality.

Another interesting way of writing this inequality is
$$
\frac{m}{2}\text{Var}_{\mu}(f) \leq \int\phi(f)d\mu - \phi\left (\int f d\mu\right )
$$
which actually lower bounds the gap (sometimes called the Jensen gap) by a typically non-negative constant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just out of curiosity, if you define a tertiary lower bounded second-order differentiable convex function $\phi(x)$ (even stronger) where $\phi(y) \geq \phi(x) +\langle \nabla f(x),(y-x) \rangle + (y-x)^{\top}\nabla ^2f(x)(y-x)) + \frac{m}{6}\|y-x\|^{3}$, would $\psi(x) = \phi(x) - \frac{m}{6} |x\|^{3}$ be a strong convex function? And thus we can do this trick again? I have not worked out the details yet, but what do you think if this can be generalized more?

Comment: I'm not certain that I full understand your comment, but the trick that can be generalized immediately is that if $\psi(x) \triangleq \phi(x) - \eta(x)$ is convex then $\phi(\int) - \eta(\int) = \psi(\int) \leq \int\psi = \int\phi - \int \eta$. Re-arrange and obtain $\phi(\int) \leq \int \phi + \eta(\int) - \int\eta$. Whether or not this works out to be nice will heavily depend on the form of $\eta$. In the world of probability a cool choice is $\eta = x\log x$ so that $\eta(\int) - \int\eta$ is what some authors call the (negative) entropy.

Comment: I see. That's indeed a nice trick. Thank you!